# My daughter pretends to be in an emergency. Do I have to help?

Tags: lying, adolescent

For the sake of argument, let's assume I'm a father. I have a daughter that calls me and says she's in danger. When I arrive, it turns out she has never been in danger and just wants a ride home (or something else).

Now, do I have to attempt to help her the second time she calls me?
What about the fifth?

Luckily, this hadn't happened yet, but I was wondering.

Comment: How old is the daughter?

Comment: What are the circumstances of this "danger" she is in? Would it be an option to answer if she is in danger she should call the police - or something adapted to where she is and what she tells you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dare say to most parents, this hasn't happened yet. This is not a normal scenario, and if it did occur, the solution would require getting to the bottom of why she feels she needs to lie to you in order to get a ride. That is, of course, difficult to do in a hypothetical scenario, so the best course of action would be unknown.

This would definitely be a behaviour you'd want to work on, but in the interim, yes, you would need to attend to your daughter's distress calls, despite the fact that she has previously cried wolf. Anything else would be negligence.

Comment: I'm aware that such behaviour would require attention. In the question, I was thinking about the legal side of view. By constitution, would it be wrong to not help? You answered that question in the second part of your reply. Thanks, that was helpful!

Comment: @ULTRACOMFY Constitutional law is about how governments work, so it isn't relevant in this case. Also, questions about legality in general would probably be better suited for the legal SE site.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal for small kids. Likely it is a need of attention which is good and healthy.

It may be dealt in a way if helping like its not a big deal and right afterwards to ask how she is in a new way talk a bit or tell when you’re available to talk.

During the talk it may be good time to tell about own duties so she understands how much of free time is possessed. If kid tries to tell something, to share some impressions then the best way is to wait and listen everything first.